# Correct path to read an image in Opencv(c++)?

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I wrote bellow code to read and show an image from a path in widows:

```
#include "SIFT.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("F:/Personal/1.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
     if (input.empty()){
         cout << "is empty";
         getchar();
         return -1;

     }
     namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);// Create a window for display.
     imshow("Display window", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    //cv::Mat* m = &input; 
    //implementSIFT s(input, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

But the image seems empty. What is correct path to read an image? 
Or Where is the problem from?

Comment: Is there really an image placed at `F:\Personal\1.jpg`?

Comment: Yes,it is a color image.

Comment: And your program prints `"is empty"` and finishes?

Comment: In OpenCV api for `imread` : "If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions, unsupported or invalid format), the function returns an empty matrix (Mat::data==NULL )"

Comment: Yes, after printing is empty, program finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct path should be :

```
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("F:\\Personal/1.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR);
```